# Download firebase files with firebase_admin python

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-admin

Good time ago I found a way to list and download a file with Firebase_admin and python but I have not found the post again, so I hope you can help me.
What I try is to list the files there are and download a file in escpecifico so far what I have tried is this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QLabel,QPushButton,QApplication,QGridLayout
from firebase_admin import db,credentials,storage
import firebase_admin

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)



        self.Button = QPushButton(self)
        self.Button.setText("Press")
        self.Button.clicked.connect(lambda:self.GetFirebase())


    def GetFirebase(self):
        cred = credentials.Certificate("accesFire.json")
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{
            'databaseURL':'https://exe-tablas.firebaseio.com/'
        })

        stor = storage.bucket()




app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
m.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```

I only remember that you had to declare the property bucket from the storage but nothing else I hope you can help me